# Webpack bundle splitting or extracting

Tags: d3.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, bundle

I want to reduce the size of my bundle more after doing the source-map and CommonChunk.

Let say I am using react-d3 library. But only the D3.PieChart is used throughout the whole application.

```
// only PieChart is used
var PieChart = require('rd3').PieChart
```

When I look into the bundle file, all other components like BarChart, blah blah are also included. Is there anyway to only include the PieChart part of react-d3 library? Same case for react and react-router, anyway to only import a portion of the library but not whole.

I am using Webpack for bundling.

Here is my webpack config:

```
var Webpack = require('webpack')

var DevelopmentEnvironmentConfig = new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
  }
})

var CommonChunkConfig = new Webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: "vendor",
  filename: "vendor_bundle.js",
  minChunks: 4
})

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
    vendor: ['react', 'react-router', 'react-dom', 'd3', 'rd3']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: "app_bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + '/public/javascripts/'
  },
    plugins: [DevelopmentEnvironmentConfig, CommonChunkConfig]
}
```

Comment: Depends on the library. E.g. lodash allows `require('lodash/cloneDeep')` and React allows `require('react-dom/server')`. Does `require('rd3/PieChart')` work?

Comment: what you are describing is called `tree-shaking`. easiest way to do it is using webpack 2

Comment: @DavidGilbertson `require('rd3/PieChart')` doesn't work but `require('rd3/build/cjs/piechart/PieChart')` does reduce a little bit. I think the problem is due to the `require('d3')` inside PieChart.js

Comment: @Deadfish In order to use `tree-shaking`, do I need to rewrite my code in ES6?

Comment: not really; refer this [blog](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/webpack-2-tree-shaking-configuration-9f1de90f3233#.yhhfsipzs) to get more idea about it